# Efficient traversing of vector of vectors and reverse mapping for faster lookup

Tags: c++, vector, big-o, stdvector, unordered-map

I have a function that returns a vector of vectors. I need to unravel and store it in a container like unordered_map so that lookup is faster.

`vector<ssc> SSC = getSsc();`

For each element from `getSsc()` say `sid` is another vector of ids say `cid`. They can look something like this:
`SSC = [s1, s2, s3, s4]` and each element of `SCC` be like:
`s1 = [c1, c2, c3, c4]`
`s2 = [c5, c6]`
`s3 = [c7]`

I need to look up for `cid` so that it returns `s2` if I query for `c5` or `c6`. I can do two for loops and populate an unordered_map container. But is there an efficient way to do this?

`c1, .... n` and `s1, .... n` are unique ids. But different `cid` can have same `sid`.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by efficient, but you can't avoid visiting all of the elements and you can't safely insert items into standard library containers from multiple threads. However, you can count the number of cids and `reserve()` space in the unordered_map. Then performance will be as good as possible, with no rehashing and linear complexity in the number of cids.

Answer (score 0):

Used the nested for loop to solve the problem. As there will be a performance bottleneck, I used the `tbb::parallel_for` to do this operation. The nested loop runs pretty fast.